Can a pitcher get a blown save, save and win in the same game?
If a pitcher blows a save in the bottom of 9th inning, then pitches 10th after his team regains lead and proceeds to shut down the opponent, would he get both a blown save, save and win?

No, the winning pitcher never gets a save. MLB rule 9.19 "Saves for relief pitchers":

The Official Scorer shall credit a pitcher with a save when such
pitcher meets all four of the following conditions:
(a) He is the finishing pitcher in a game won by his team;
(b) He is not the winning pitcher;
[ some more stuff which doesn't matter here ]


There's another question about a pitcher getting both a blown save and a win.
But it is not possible for a pitcher to get both a blown save and a save, or a win and a save.
To get a save, you must enter the game in a "save situation" (your team is ahead), and not allow your team to relinquish the lead.
If your team loses the lead, you can get the blown save and are now ineligible for a save.
